# How do I determine if something is an Array or Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Array and object are the only inputs . Is there a simple function that can determine whether a variable is an array or object?

Comment: have you checked this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834126/how-to-efficiently-check-if-variable-is-array-or-object-in-nodejs-v8

Comment: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html .. worth looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there are many other similar answers but this is one way:

```
if ({}.toString.call(obj) == '[object Object]') {
  // is an object
}

if ({}.toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]') {
  // is an array
}
```

This can be turned into a nifty function:

```
function typeOf(obj) {
  return {}.toString.call(obj).match(/\w+/g)[1].toLowerCase();
}

if (typeOf(obj) == 'array') ...
```

This works for any type:

```
if (typeOf(obj) == 'date') // is a date
if (typeOf(obj) == 'number') // is a number
...
```

Comment: +1, but you should use `Object.prototype.toString` as the `toString` method of the global/window object may not produce an appropriate result. :-)

Comment: I guess it depends on how much browser support you need. This should work on modern browsers AFAIK. It defaults to `window.toString` which is an object. Otherwise I'd prefer `{}.toString`. But you're right.

Comment: In Firefox, `window.toString.call(obj)` returns `[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]`. Note that `window` is a host object so not bound to comply with rules for native objects. Also, the [global object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1) is not an instance of Object (it doesn't have a `[[Prototype]]` property defined by ECMA-262 either), it's a special object that exists before any other.

Comment: Just updated to use the proper (shorter) way that should work on all modern browsers. AFAIK only IE7- has problems that can be easily solved with `({}).toString`. I've been using `window.toString` without problems tho in browsers that I need to target, but I see the trouble.

Comment: I guess the last caveat is that this may not work with host objects, it may even throw an error, but it should be OK in the OP's case.

Answer (score 1):

`(variable instanceof Array)` will return true for arrays.

You could also use `variable.isArray()`, but this is not supported by older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.isArray()`:

```
if(Array.isArray(myVar)) {
    // myVar is an array
} else {
    // myVar is not an array
}
```

As long as you know it will be one or the other you are set.  Otherwise, combine this with `typeof`:

```
if(typeof myVar === "object") {
    if(Array.isArray(myVar)) {
        // myVar is an array
    } else {
        // myVar is a non-array object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First check if it is an  [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) Array and then if it of object type.

```
if(variable instanceof Array)
{
//this is an array. This needs to the first line to be checked 
//as an array instanceof Object is also true

}
else if(variable instanceof Object)
{
//it is an object
}
```

Comment: Fails if the object is passed across a frame as it will be created from a different instance of Array and Object.