# Why does JSON.stringify not serialize non-enumerable properties?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I'm serializing objects to JSON strings with JavaScript,

I noticed only enumerable object properties get serialized:

```
var a = Object.create(null,{
  x: { writable:true, configurable:true, value: "hello",enumerable:false },
  y: { writable:true, configurable:true, value: "hello",enumerable:true }
});
document.write(JSON.stringify(a)); //result is {"y":"hello"}
```

<sup>[[pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CmAys)]</sup>

I'm wondering why that is? I've searched through the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), the [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) parser documentation. 
I could not find this behavior documented any-where.

I suspect this is the result of using `for... in` loops that [only go through [[enumerable]]](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4) properties (at least in the case of `json2`). This can probably be done with something like `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` that returns both enumerable, and non-enumerable properties. 
That might be problematic to serialize though (due to deserialization).

**tl;dr**

- Why does `JSON.stringify` only serialize enumerable properties?
- Is this behavior documented anywhere?
- How can I implement serializing non-enumerable properties myself?

Comment: If you set enumerable to false, there will be no instance added. Try console logging the object before you stringify it, and you'll see that `x` is missing from the object itself, so it surely can't be there once it's stringified.

Comment: @adeneo that's presumably because it also uses something like stringify and not getOwnPropertyNames. Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a) returns ["x","y"] and if you type obj.x you get "hello".

Comment: Yes I've noticed, and that's a good indication that you should probably reconsider and find another way to create your object.

Comment: @adeneo Enumerable properties serve a purpose. In the very basic sample input absolutely. However, this question is a _very reduced_ case of what I'm actually doing. Thanks for the input and time.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - As a side note for `Object.create`, enumerable will default to false unless explicitly defined. Here is a sample jsfiddle showing the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/T3PGD/2/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's specified in the [ES5 spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.12.3).

> 10. If Type(*value*) is Object, and IsCallable(*value*) is false
>
>     - a. If the [[Class]] internal property of *value* is `"Array"` then
>
>       - i. Return the result of calling the abstract operation *JA* with argument *value*.
>     - b. Else, return the result of calling the abstract operation *JO* with argument *value*.

So, let's look at JO. Here's the relevant section:

> Let K be an internal List of Strings consisting of the names of **all the own properties of value whose [[Enumerable]] attribute is true**. The ordering of the Strings should be the same as that used by the Object.keys standard built-in function.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea stringify was part of the spec, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @ThiefMaster answered above, it's specified in the spec

however, if you know the names of the non-enumerable properties you like to be serialized ahead of time, you can achieve it by passing a replacer function as the second param to JSON.stringify() ([documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter)),  like so

```js
var o = {
  prop: 'propval',
}

Object.defineProperty(o, 'propHidden', {
  value: 'propHiddenVal',
  enumerable: false,
  writable: true,
  configurable: true
});

var s = JSON.stringify(o, (key, val) => {
  if (!key) {
    // Initially, the replacer function is called with an empty string as key representing the object being stringified. It is then called for each property on the object or array being stringified.
    if (typeof val === 'object' && val.hasOwnProperty('propHidden')) {
      Object.defineProperty(val, 'propHidden', {
        value: val.propHidden,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
      });

    }
  }
  return val;
});

console.log(s);
```

Comment: Sadly, with this solution the non-enumerable properties are enumerable after the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a generic `JSON.stringify()` that includes non-enumerables with code ***like*** below. But first, some notes:

- This code has **not** been thoroughly tested for possible bugs or unexpected behavior; also, it turns functions into basic objects. Treat accordingly.
- `copyEnumerable()` is the function to pay attention to. It does not itself internally call `JSON.stringify()` (you can do that yourself, with the output object) mainly because recursive calls to `JSON.stringify()` (due to nested objects) will yield uglier, unwanted results.
- I'm only checking for `object` and `function` types to be treated specially; I **believe** that these are the only types which need to be handled specially... Note that JS `Arrays` (`[]`) fall into this category (objects), as well as classes (functions), and `null` does not. Since `null` is of type `object`, I included the `!!` check.
- The `stopRecursiveCopy` `Set` is just to make sure it's not doing infinite recursion.
- I'm using a trick with the 2 extra parameters to `JSON.stringify()` calls to make it output something formatted prettier, for easy reading.

---

The code is in an easy format to try out and tweak in the console:

```js
{
  o = {};
  d = {};
  Object.defineProperties(o, {
    a: {
      value: 5,
      enumerable: false
    },
    b: {
      value: "test",
      enumerable: false
    },
    c: {
      value: {},
      enumerable: false
    }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(o.c, "d", {
    value: 7,
    enumerable: false
  });

  //The code to use (after careful consideration!).
  function isObject(testMe) {
    return ((typeof(testMe) === "object" && !!testMe) ||
      typeof(testMe) === "function");
  }
  let stopRecursiveCopy = new Set();
  function copyEnumerable(obj) {
    if (!isObject(obj)) {
      return obj;
    }
    let enumerableCopy = {};
    for (let key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)) {
      if (isObject(obj[key])) {
        if (!stopRecursiveCopy.has(obj[key])) {
          stopRecursiveCopy.add(obj[key]);
          enumerableCopy[key] = copyEnumerable(obj[key]);
          stopRecursiveCopy.delete(obj[key]);
        }
      } else {
        enumerableCopy[key] = obj[key];
      }
    }
    return enumerableCopy;
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(copyEnumerable(o), null, "  "));

  Object.defineProperty(copyEnumerable, "test", {
    value: 10,
    enumerable: false
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(copyEnumerable(copyEnumerable), null, "  "));

  Object.defineProperty(o, "f", {
    value: copyEnumerable,
    enumerable: false
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(copyEnumerable(o), null, "  "));
}
```

which outputs:

```js
//o
{
  "a": 5,
  "b": "test",
  "c": {
    "d": 7
  }
}

//copyEnumerable itself
{
  "test": 10,
  "prototype": {
    "constructor": {
      "test": 10,
      "length": 1,
      "name": "copyEnumerable"
    }
  },
  "length": 1,
  "name": "copyEnumerable"
}

//o again, but with `f: copyEnumerable` added
{
  "a": 5,
  "b": "test",
  "c": {
    "d": 7
  },
  "f": {
    "test": 10,
    "prototype": {},
    "length": 1,
    "name": "copyEnumerable"
  }
}
```

---

Pertinent links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706877/1599699
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538851/1599699

Comment: And you may be wondering why I bothered to figure all this out... Because `console.log(JSON.stringify(new Error("HERRO")))` outputs `{}`, and `console.log(JSON.stringify(copyEnumerable(new Error("HERRO"))))` outputs `{"fileName":"debugger eval code","lineNumber":1,"columnNumber":43,"message":"HERRO"}`...