# Iterating over non-enumerable properties

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-5, enumerable

I have used `Object.defineProperty` and `enumerable: false` to define a few properties on a config object. There is however one place in my module where I would like to iterate over the non-enumerable properties as well as the enumerable ones. Is it possible to do this without keeping a list of property names elsewhere?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess you could use [`getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) which returns properties, enumerable or not.

From the docs:

> Returns an array of all properties (enumerable or not) found directly
>   upon a given object.

Comment: An example where I needed this in my project: Looping through all the Math functions/constants. var mathProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math); mathProps is then ["E", "LN10", "LN2" .... ]

Comment: @DanielHoward Yes, but it also includes `toSource`; which you probably don't want. In general, you'd need to be sure to filter the results to exactly what you expect (either with a whitelist or a blacklist), so it's probably only useful in introspection or serialization code, and things like that, where you're applying a general operation which doesn't care which properties are returned (or which object is passed to it), it just needs all of them.