# Where the object? How to obtain simple key-value pair about error message?

Tags: node.js, axios

This code is using axios and its error object, but is wrong because the key not exist,

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios.get('http://w3c.org/error_here').then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.Error) // not exist
  });
```

This other code is working fine, but there are no clues about how to solve the problem to output only the error message (supposed before `error.Error`).

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('http://w3c.org/error_here')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  }).catch(error => {
    delete error.request
    delete error.config
    delete error.response
    console.log(error)  // a string here!
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))  // where??
  });
```

The first `console.log()` output is a string

```
   Error: Request failed with status code 404 ...
```

the second is an empty object,

```
    {}
```

So, where the string (or the object)? How to do something as `console.log(error.Error)` to show **only** the error message?

Comment: what exactly are you looking for, not very clear with your question?

Comment: Thanks @naga-elixir-jar, I edited, check if it make sense now

Comment: `Request failed with status code 404` this is message and its availabe as `error.message`

Comment: If you want to see the full error object check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object `console.log(JSON.stringify(error))` will throw an error reason being `error` object is circular

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar, YES (!),    `console.log(error.message)` is working!  Well, the answer of the question must be also theoretic , "why `JSON.stringify(error))` was empty?

Comment: on futher testing looks like the `error.message` is part of the stack trace, so somewhere on the `prototype` chain (set `hidden: true` in the link above)

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar, hum... 1. when run `node myScript.js > out.txt`  there are no STDERR message, so it is not a confusion;   2. adding `util.inspect(error, {showHidden: false})`  I not see the key "message", so no clues about the existence of a "hidden key" in the object, very very strange, seems a **bug** in the NodeJS compiler or axios lib.

Comment: set `showHidden` to `true` and you'll see the object.

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar oops, but no changes, I tested both, same obscure text, no clues about "message" key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting the comments into an answer:

When you used `delete`, you deleted all the `enumerable` members of the object:

```
delete error.request
delete error.config
delete error.response
```

```
console.log(Object.keys(error)); // Object.keys gets all non-enumerable properties' key of the object into an array
// outputs
[ 'config', 'request', 'response' ]
```

`message` is a `non-enumerable` property

```
console.log(error.propertyIsEnumerable('message'));
// outputs
false
```

Finally, `JSON.stringify(error)` is empty because `stringify` [does not serialize `non-enumerable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733878/why-does-json-stringify-not-serialize-non-enumerable-properties)

More about `enumerable` on [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) and [`SO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893718/what-does-enumerable-mean)

---

How to list the non-enumerable properties of the *error* object? That is, how to discover that a key named "message" exist?
List all with:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error));
```

After deletes, what's left is `[ 'stack', 'message' ]`.

Comment: you've got it :)