# Why JSON.string is ommiting some values?

Tags: javascript, json, next.js

```
console.log(saveState) //IT RETURNS {user: {lat: -20.8213224, lng: -49.3581463}}
console.log(typeof saveState) //RETURNS "object"
console.log(JSON.stringify(saveState)) //RETURNS {"user":{}}
```

Why is it happening, what i'm doing wrong? I'm using Javascript

This is the code of the error:
I'm trying to take states from localStorage, and send it to redux Storage.
I'm coding in Next.JS + Redux

Codes below

app.tsx

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { localStorageKeys, storeWrapper } from '../store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { userUpdate } from '../store/actions/users'
import GlobalStyle from '../styles/global'
import { Navbar } from '../components/Navbar'
import CategorySelector from '../components/CategorySelector'
import Head from 'next/head'

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const {store, props} = storeWrapper.useWrappedStore(pageProps)

  useEffect(()=>{
    let state: any = localStorage.getItem(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_KEY||"")
   
    if(state){
        try{
            state = JSON.parse(state)
            if(state.user){
              if(!state.user.lat || !state.user.lng){
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos)=>{
                  state.user.lat = pos.coords.latitude;
                  state.user.lng = pos.coords.longitude;
                })
              }
            }
            else{
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos)=>{
                state.user.lat = pos.coords.latitude;
                state.user.lng = pos.coords.longitude;
              })
            }
            
        }catch{
            state = {}
        }
    }else{
        state = {}

        state.user = {}
        
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos)=>{
          state.user.lat = pos.coords.latitude,
          state.user.lng = pos.coords.longitude
        })
    }

    Object.entries(localStorageKeys).map((val, index)=>{
      const [ref, key] = val
      if(state[ref]){
        switch(ref){
          case 'user':
            store.dispatch(userUpdate(state[key]))
            break
          default:
            break
        }
      }
    })
  })

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Navbar />
      <CategorySelector />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here is the function that isn't working well, when I'm trying to convert the state to string to save, it returns nothing, but when it is in object type, it returns lat and lng properly
saveState.ts

```
export const saveState = (key: string, value: any) => {
    let state: any = localStorage.getItem(keyName)
    console.log("SAVE", key, value)
    if(state){
        try{
            state = JSON.parse(state)
        }catch{
            state = {}
        }
    }else{
        state = {}
    }

    state[key] = value

    const saveState = state

    console.log(saveState)
    console.log(typeof saveState)
    console.log(JSON.stringify({saveState}))
    
    localStorage.setItem(keyName, JSON.stringify(state))
}
```

I really dont know what to do

Comment: I've converted your question into a runnable code snippet, where you can observe that the code is working as expected.  Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you're trying to describe.

Comment: @David the code you've added does not reproduce the issue.

Comment: @David that's obviously not what the object looks like. Your edit is unhelpful

Comment: It's obvious that `saveState` is not a normal object, but please [edit] your post to include details where it came from and how it's defined. Otherwise it's impossible for us to tell what is going on.

Comment: @VLAZ: Yes, that's exactly the point.  The code shown *doesn't* demonstrate the problem.  The OP is encouraged to provide a [mcve] which *does* demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @mousetail: Yes, that's exactly the point.  The code shown *doesn't* demonstrate the problem.  The OP is encouraged to provide a [mcve] which *does* demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @David Editing the post with a obviously not reproducible example is not a good way to encourage adding a reproducible example. The post is bad but your edit only made it worse.

Comment: @David *your* code makes it a completely different issue. Yes, details are needed but making up obviously wrong ones isn't helpful, either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733878/why-does-json-stringify-not-serialize-non-enumerable-properties might help

Comment: Either the properties are not enumerable and own. Or, the object is populated with those properties after the stringify line runs (`console.log(saveState)` will show the updated object because it keeps a reference)

Comment: The problem is that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` updates the user object asynchronously. You're calling `JSON.stringify` before the properties are being created.