# $.parseJSON(resp); if resp is number it works

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was using this to test if server returned data is json.

```
try {
    json = $.parseJSON(resp);
} catch (error) {
    json = null;
}

if (json) {
    //
} else {
    //
}
```

But it returns true if resp is a number lik 2 or 3 or... It returns null if resp is 0.

Any ideas how to avoid this false situation?

I'm outputting data using php:

```
echo 0; //returns null
echo 2; //returns as valid json
```

It appears, 0 is read as string, and 2 is read as number.

Comment: I don't get `null` when I test it. And what is meant by "returns true"? Are you using the result as a condition? If so, `0` is falsey. More info is needed

Comment: Do you want to know if `json` is an object ? If so use `typeof json==="object"`.

Comment: `$.parseJSON('0');` works but `$.parseJSON(0);` returns null.

Comment: @dystroy I'm trying to understand if response is valid json.

Comment: Your variable `resp` HAVE to be type of `string`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: `$.parseJSON(2)` would also be `null`.

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes, that's my point. Strings work, numbers don't.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: My point is that other numbers worked, so we're certainly dealing with  strings.

Comment: @cookiemonster Unless OP was comparing strings before and numbers now. As it stands now, the question doesn't present enough information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I updated OP.

Comment: Can you inspect the actual HTTP response, e.g. in your browser's developer console or in fiddler? I suspect the real problem is how your sending the response from the server.

Comment: What you're not showing is the manner in which you've tested the response that has caused you to determine that `json` is `null`

Comment: @cookiemonster added that too.

Comment: Please see my [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747288/parsejsonresp-if-resp-is-number-it-works?noredirect=1#comment31089299_20747288). When you do `if (json) {`, the `0` value is falsey, just like `null`.

Comment: @cookiemonster omg, you are right! I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Nah, but it always helps to post a full example. ;-)

Comment: @cookiemonster I thought I had major inconsistency at hand :P

Comment: Just FYI, in JavaScript, the falsey values are `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, `false` and `""` *(empty string)*.

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting an integer, use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
try {
    val = parseInt(resp, 10);

    if(val > 0) /* act accordingly ... */
} catch (error) {
    val = null;
}
```

If you want to know if the "JSON is valid," you can use something akin to the following:

```
function isValidJSON(string){
    try { 
        $.parseJSON(string);
        return true;
    }
    catch(e){ return false; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not expecting an integer. I use integers for error messages.

Comment: @salivan Use HTTP error code for that ! Don't send an error message in place of a data value !

Comment: @dystroy: Sometimes errors are internal messages that are not HTTP or REST related.

Comment: @cookiemonster exactly my case.

Comment: @cookiemonster 1) http error codes include server error. 2) if it's not enough, if semantically the error is part of the message, data can **contain** the error : `{"error":34}`. A sane protocol shouldn't use polymorphic data where the signification is deduced from the type of the value.

Comment: I agree with @dystroy that such errors should be communicated as part of a structure as he shows instead of just a plain number.

Comment: @dystroy agreed. Will do that in my next app :)

Comment: Regarding your second example, I'm doing exactly the same thing. And it is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like:

```
// source from Angular source
function isJson(data) { 
  return (/^\s*[\[\{]/.test(data) && /[\}\]]\s*$/.test(data));
};
```

So...

```
if (isJson(resp))
  json = $.parseJSON(resp);
else
  alert ('another response: ' + resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers like `2` or `3` are technically valid JSON data. Do you expect an object? See e.g. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-variable-is-an-object) for methods of checking if the returned variable is an object.

Basically your workflow would be to try to parse it as JSON, and if it succeeds, check if it's an object/list (depending on what you expect).

Example:

```
try {
    json = $.parseJSON(resp);
    return (typeof(json) === "object")
} catch (error) {
    json = null;
}
```

Comment: A number doesn't make, according to the spec, a valid message : *"JSON-text = object / array"*

Comment: @dystroy This is true in respect to the JSON spec, but Javascript doesn't handle it that way. E.g. execute `JSON.parse("3")` in Node.JS, it yields 3.

Comment: @UliKöhler: But it doesn't handle `"0"` any differently than `"2"` or `"3"`.

Comment: @cookiemonster Do you think parsing "0" is the main problem here? I assumed the main question here is how to see the difference between numbers (including "0") and "JSON" (probably objects). To me, "0" returning false is just a sidenote.

Comment: I was only responding to your answer where you say that numbers like `2` or `3` are technically valid. Numbers like `0` aren't any different. We don't know what the actual issue is because `0` will not give `null` in the example in the question.