# Sorting nested objects of objects by key - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to sort an object based on ascending keys. The solution I implemented only works for one level deep and I would like to get it done for a nested object. Please advice.

```js
var data = {
  player2: {
    score: 6,
    cards: 4
  },
  player1: {
    score: 4,
    cards: 6
  }
};

console.log(Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).sort()
))
```

The end result I want is

```
var data = {
  player1: {
    cards: 6,       
    score: 4,
  },
  player2: {
    cards: 4,
    score: 6
  }
};
```

I might have a very big nested object. Please advice.

Comment: have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629917/sorting-javascript-object-by-key-value-recursively I hope it helps.

Comment: if you have a large object of "players" it would be much better to have an array of objects... let data = [ {id: 'Player1', score: 6, cards 4}, {id: 'player2', score:4, cards: 6}]

Comment: @GifCo Its the redux store in React. I am sorting it for readability in redux dev tools