# Sort object and nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object that needs to be sorted in descending order and a nested object within this object that needs to be sorted in descending order.

```
      "carDetails": {
        "suvPrice": 60,
        "suvSavings": {
          "10% Off": 10,
          "20% Off": 20,
          "Fire Sale": 30
        },
        "truckPrice": 90,
        "truckSavings": {
          "10% Off": 10,
          "Buy Now": 40
        }
      }
```

it should display in this order:
truckPrice: 90
truckSavings:
Buy Now: 40
10% Off: 10

suvPrice: 60
suvSavings:
Fire Sale: 30
20% Off: 20
10% Off: 10

Is this possible given it's an object? I've tried converting to an array using Object.entries, but this turns each key, value into an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to sort/order keys in JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658690/is-there-a-way-to-sort-order-keys-in-javascript-objects)

Comment: I would suggest looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24629917/4476484).