# Why does JavaScript JSON evaluate to false?

Tags: javascript

Why is that:

```
var bla = {
    "1":"1",
    "2":"2"    
}

console.log(bla === true)
```

is false ?

http://jsfiddle.net/nottinhill/jdxvnea1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `bla` is an **object** not a `boolean`.

```
console.log(typeof bla === 'object') //logs true
```

[check this Q/A for more help on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-variable-is-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

By using `===` you are comparing without doing a type conversion, so variable with different types will never be equal.

```
> bla = {"1": "1", "2": "2"}

> bla == true
=> false

> bla === true
=> false

> bla === false
=> false

> Boolean(bla) === true        // Do it like this
=> true
```

Comment: bla == true => true is not correct. please show me jsfiddle where it works like you say.

Comment: @SirBenBenji Yes, it's not, thus the comment `// Do it like this`, I don't know how it got there, I left my computer for a few moments HA HA...

Answer (score 1):

Your bla is an object and false is boolean.

- Strict equality **===**

The identity operator returns true if the operands are strictly equal (see above) with no type conversion.

- Equality **==**

The equality operator converts the operands if they are not of the same type, then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the string operand is converted to a number if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

Sources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score 0):

you cannot equate a object to a boolean. you can do with the object index or check for the existence of the object like this

```
console.log(bla[1] == true)
or 
if(bla)  { console.log(true); }
```