# Check if an object literal is an 'object'

Tags: javascript

Why does the `if statement` not work, `typeof` says obj is an object.

```
var obj = {};
console.log(typeof obj);

if(obj === 'object') { console.log('working');}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a variable is an object in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-variable-is-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if (typeof obj === 'object')
```

or

```
if (typeof obj == 'object')
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
if (typeof obj === 'object')
```

for checking if the type is an object.

```js
var obj = {};
document.write(typeof obj + '<br>');
if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    document.write('working');
}
```