# How can I detect ES5 object types in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

According to the spec there are only 6 types, 5 of which are native ( Null, Undefined, Number, String, Boolean ) and 1 which is of type Object.

[Googled it.](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how%20to%20detect%20native%20types%20in%20JavaScript)

It appears that `typeof` fails for `null` and detects it as an object.

It also seems that `toString()` will report Object descendants as their descendant type, for example `RegExp`, `Function`, etc.

I don't want the descendant type, I want `RegExp`, `Function`, etc. reported as `Object`.

I basically want to detect true ES5 Objects.

Comment: [_.isObject](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/96430fd5458b20dab73e4b11ee71fb99012f5759/dist/lodash.core.js#L2747)

Comment: what's the point of this novel grouping?

Comment: `!{string:1,number:1,boolean:1,undefined:1}[typeof value]`

Comment: The answer is close but not correct, why is this marked as a duplicate.  I'm looking for **objects as defined by ES5**

Comment: @Bergi, the question you referenced does not directly address thie question being asked here.

Comment: @MjrKusanagi [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22482737/1048572) to the duplicate question does exactly address brannon's problem and provides all known solutions for it.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks. I see that now, sorry.

Comment: @brannon .. `function es5_type(query){return (query===null ? "null" : typeof query==="function" ? "object" : typeof query);}`

Comment: @Bergi - The question is vague that is why it has a gazillion answers.  I think I found the second law of thermodynamics some where in there ... but no ... close my question which is more specific ( better ).

Answer (score -3):

Taken from [angularjs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L505):

```
function isObject(value) {
  // http://jsperf.com/isobject4
  return value !== null && typeof value === 'object';
}
```

Comment: That fails on function objects.

Comment: It does but at least he understood the question.

Comment: Could be elaborated on, and yes it kinda provides a failed case lol.