# Inherit Method to All Objects Except Primitives

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I want to add a method that is capable of working on all objects. Preferably it should not exist on primitives (number, boolean, string, symbol), on which it cannot work.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Using Object.prototype does not work because the primitive types inherit from Object.

Comment: Define "working". Do you mean a function that appears in the prototype of every object in JS?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin adding a property, which does not work on primitives.

Comment: I mean Object.prototype.test = 1; true.test == 1

Comment: @DanielHerr It seems you are misunderstanding what happens in that code. It's the object wrapper who inherits the `test` property, not `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the function on the prototype of `Object`, then set the corresponding member on the prototypes of the constructors where you don't want it to `undefined`:

```
Object.prototype.foo = function() { alert("foo"); };
Number.prototype.foo = undefined;
var x = {};
var y = 10;
x.foo(); // works
y.foo(); // TypeError: y.foo is not a function
```

I don't know why you're doing this, and it seems like a code smell, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

**Primitives are not objects and don't inherit from anywhere**. They can be wrapped in objects which do inherit from `Object.prototype`, but these are objects.

It might look like primitives inherit properties, but under the hood these are accessed on the object wrappers, not the primitives. When [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getvalue) resolves a property reference,

> - If [HasPrimitiveBase](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reference-specification-type)(*V*) is true, then
>
>   - [Assert](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-algorithm-conventions): In this case, *base* will never be null or undefined.
>   - Let *base* be [ToObject](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toobject)(*base*).
> - Return *base*.[[Get]]([GetReferencedName](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reference-specification-type)(*V*), [GetThisValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getthisvalue)(*V*)).

So if the base of the reference was a primitive, it will be converted to an object before attempting to get the property.

But as @nnnnnn notes, when you [call the method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-evaluatecall), the `this` value will be the primitive, because the base of the reference didn't change. Note in sloppy mode it will be coerced to an object.

In fact, you could take advantage of this and test whether the `this` value [is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39187058/1529630), if what you want is prevent primitives from being used as bases of references when calling the method:

```
Object.prototype.method = function() {
  "use strict";
  if(Object(this) !== this) {
    throw Error('This method can only be called on objects');
  }
  // ...
  return "works";
};
true.method(); // Error: This method can only be called on objects
new Boolean(true).method(); // "works"
```

Comment: I understand the distinction you're making, but...even your own example `true.self()` shows that you can take a primitive and directly call the method from `Object.prototype`. (I say "directly" in the sense that in the code you don't explicitly convert or wrap anything, it just "works".) Also, think about what happens if you add `"use strict";` to your function...

Answer (score 0):

Streamlined way of removing the method from primitives.

```
Object.prototype.test = function() { }

for(let { prototype } of [ String, Number, Boolean, Symbol ]) {
 prototype.test = undefined
}
```