# How can we prove that javascript functions are objects?

Tags: javascript, function, object

i am using

```
var foo = function(){}
```

`typeof(foo)` - returns function instead of Object

while javascript concept tell that all function in javascript are objects?

Comment: The fact that they are created as expression and that they can be assigned, compared (by reference) and that you can add arbitrary properties should suffice, no?

Answer (score 6):

First and foremost, there's the fact that the specification explicitly states they're objects, in a lot of places, including [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-function) where it defines the term "function":

> **function**
>
> member of the Object type that may be invoked as a subroutine

Empirically, there are lots of ways to prove it, but one of the simplest is to assign a value to a property on it:

```js
var foo = function() { };
foo.myProperty = "my value";
console.log(foo.myProperty); // "my value"
```

Or use one as a prototype (which is unusual, but possible), which proves it as only objects can be prototypes:

```js
var foo = function() { };
var obj = Object.create(foo);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === foo); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this for a test

```
>  x = function(){}
<- function (){}
>  x.a = "Asd"
<- "Asd"
>  x
<- function (){}
>  x.a
<- "Asd"
```

Doing the same on an integer will result in undefined assignment

```
>  x = 1
<- 1
>  x.a = 123
<- 123
>  x
<- 1
>  x.a
<- undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

See my [list of proper ways to test if a value belongs to the Object type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39187058/1529630).

They detect functions as objects, e.g.

```
var func = function(){};
Object(func) === func; // true  -->  func is an object
```

If you want a more formal proof you will need to see the spec, for example in [ECMAScript Overview](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ecmascript-overview)

> a function is a callable object

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this very simply:

```js
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype));
console.log(Object.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype));

// or, being evil
Object.prototype.testFn = () => console.log('Exists on all objects');
({}).testFn();
[].testFn();
(new Number(5)).testFn();
Math.sqrt.testFn();
```

The first two lines demonstrate that the next step in the prototype chain beyond `Function.prototype` is `Object.prototype`.

The other lines show that you can add a property to `Object.prototype` (**seriously don't do this ever**) and it exists on all objects. In this case, we test it on an empty object, an empty array, a `Number` object and on the `Math.sqrt` function. By adding a property (a function in this case) to `Object.prototype`, all the others gain the property too.

Answer (score 0):

console.log(Function.prototype instanceof Object);