# parsing unkwon response to table ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am using an API to get response, In ajax `success`, I get this kind of response

```
{
  "Capabilities": {
    "System": {
      "SystemLogging": "true",
      "SystemBackup": "true",
      "StorageConfiguration": "false",
      "RemoteDiscovery": "true",
      "HttpSystemLogging": "false",
      "HttpSystemBackup": "true",
      "HttpSupportInformation": "false",
      "HttpFirmwareUpgrade": "true",
      "FirmwareUpgrade": "true",
      "DiscoveryResolve": "false",
      "DiscoveryBye": "true"
    },
    "Security": {
      "X.509Token": "false",
      "UsernameToken": "true",
      "TLS1.2": "false",
      "TLS1.1": "false",
      "TLS1.0": "false",
      "SupportedEAPMethods": "0",
      "SAMLToken": "false",
      "RemoteUserHandling": "false",
      "RELToken": "false",
      "OnboardKeyGeneration": "false",
      "MaxUsers": "32",
      "MaxUserNameLength": "32",
      "MaxPasswordLength": "16",
      "KerberosToken": "false",
      "HttpDigest": "true",
      "Dot1X": "false",
      "DefaultAccessPolicy": "true",
      "AccessPolicyConfig": "false"
    },
    "Network": {
      "ZeroConfiguration": "true",
      "NTP": "1",
      "IPVersion6": "true",
      "IPFilter": "true",
      "HostnameFromDHCP": "true",
      "DynDNS": "true",
      "Dot1XConfigurations": "0",
      "Dot11Configuration": "false",
      "DHCPv6": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to parse this to `table`, But instead of that just to try out, I am appending it to `xmp` tag. But its coming as an [object Object]. Even if I do parseJSON, I get error for that.

```
  "<xmp>
    #{data}
  </xm>
```

Is it possible to make something more dynamic that , It may handle that response?

UPDATE: I tried using https://github.com/abodelot/jquery.json-viewer it worked good but I want to parse it table is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON.stringify() to transform response data in a string, which you can display, then you can put the result in your xmp tag.

```
$("xmp").text(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Of course if you need to display your JSON hierarchically you've to do some work on iterating on the data properties, keep track of properties level and so on.

EDIT

I prepared an couple of dirty examples for showing how iterating over your json properties. 
The first one makes a row for each sub-object in json data. The second prints a columns for each 'leaf' property in the json data. The basic is the

```
  for(key in obj)
```

iterator which allows iterating over an object's property. ALso there's the use of the jquery's `$.type`  function which allows checking if a variable is an object for simple objects. The matter on how to detect if a var is an object in pure JS may be complex, if you want you can have a look at [Check if a value is an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript)

```js
var data={
  "Capabilities": {
    "System": {
      "SystemLogging": "true",
      "SystemBackup": "true",
      "StorageConfiguration": "false",
      "RemoteDiscovery": "true",
      "HttpSystemLogging": "false",
      "HttpSystemBackup": "true",
      "HttpSupportInformation": "false",
      "HttpFirmwareUpgrade": "true",
      "FirmwareUpgrade": "true",
      "DiscoveryResolve": "false",
      "DiscoveryBye": "true"
    },
    "Security": {
      "X.509Token": "false",
      "UsernameToken": "true",
      "TLS1.2": "false",
      "TLS1.1": "false",
      "TLS1.0": "false",
      "SupportedEAPMethods": "0",
      "SAMLToken": "false",
      "RemoteUserHandling": "false",
      "RELToken": "false",
      "OnboardKeyGeneration": "false",
      "MaxUsers": "32",
      "MaxUserNameLength": "32",
      "MaxPasswordLength": "16",
      "KerberosToken": "false",
      "HttpDigest": "true",
      "Dot1X": "false",
      "DefaultAccessPolicy": "true",
      "AccessPolicyConfig": "false"
    },
    "Network": {
      "ZeroConfiguration": "true",
      "NTP": "1",
      "IPVersion6": "true",
      "IPFilter": "true",
      "HostnameFromDHCP": "true",
      "DynDNS": "true",
      "Dot1XConfigurations": "0",
      "Dot11Configuration": "false",
      "DHCPv6": "true"
    }
  }
};

function inspect(obj, level){
  retVal="";
  for(key in obj){
    if ($.type(obj[key])==="object"){
        
        retVal=retVal+"<tr><td><strong>"+key+"</strong></td></tr>"+inspect(obj[key])+"<BR>";
    }
    else {
       retVal=retVal+"<td><strong>"+ key+"</strong>:"+obj[key]+"</td>";            
    }
  }
  return retVal;
     
}
                                  
function toTable(obj, aTable){
  if(aTable==="undefined"|| aTable===null){
    aTable={};
    aTable.header=[];
    aTable.data=[]
  }
  
  for(key in obj){
    if ($.type(obj[key])==="object"){
      aTable=toTable(obj[key],aTable);    
    }
    else {
       aTable.header.push(key);
       aTable.data.push(obj[key]);
    }
  }
  return aTable;
     
}


var ret="<table id='tabular'>"+inspect(data)+"</table>";
$("#datas").html(ret);

var asTable=toTable(data,null);
var myTable="<table id='tabular2'><tr>";
for(var i=0;i<asTable.header.length;i++){
  myTable=myTable+"<td><strong>"+asTable.header[i]+"</strong></td>";
}
myTable=myTable+"</tr><tr>";
for(var i=0;i<asTable.data.length;i++){
  myTable=myTable+"<td>"+asTable.data[i]+"</td>";
}
myTable=myTable+"</tr></table>";
$("#datas2").html(myTable);
```

```css
#tabular td {border:1px solid gray};
#tabular {border:1px solid gray; border-collapse:collapse}

#tabular2 td {border:1px solid blue};
#tabular2 {border:1px solid blue; border-collapse:collapse}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <h3> EXAMPLE 1</h3>
  <div id="datas">
  </div>
  <!--<br><br>&nbsp;<br>-->
  <h3> EXAMPLE 2</h3>    
  <div id="datas2">
  </div>
```

Comment: what about parsing that data to a table? with uknown key and values?

Comment: Loop on obj properties, check if they are.objs and so on. How the table should be made?

Comment: table should be simple using only parent keys as header how the values..

Comment: have a look to my answer, it could be a good starting point. Then you probably have to work on it a little bit