# How to check if array contains at least one object ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to check if array contains object or not. I am not trying to compare values just want to check in my array if object is present or not?

Ex.

```
$arr = ['a','b','c'] // normal
$arr = [{ id: 1}, {id: 2}] // array of objects
$arr = [{id: 1}, {id:2}, 'a', 'b'] // mix values
```

So how can i check if array contains object

Comment: will it always be id? or it can change?

Comment: Loop through array items and test if it's object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: Are you looking for a specific value, or just if the array contains "any object"?

Comment: @shv22  .object can be anything

Comment: @Cerbrus just want check if array contains an object.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `some` method which tests whether at least one element in the `array` passes the `test` implemented by the **provided** function.

```js
let arr = [{id: 1}, {id:2}, 'a', 'b'];
let exists = arr.some(a => typeof a == 'object');
console.log(exists);
```

Comment: @parth, `some` method provide a callback test function for ever item from the array. The `test` function check if array item is object. The `condition` is if `typeof a` is object.`some` method returns true if `at least` one item from the array satifiy the condition.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to check if array contains object or not

Use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to simply check if any item of the array has value of type "object"

```
var hasObject = $arr.some( function(val){
   return typeof val == "object";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var hasObject = function(arr) {
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] == 'object') {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

console.log(hasObject(['a','b','c']));
console.log(hasObject([{ id: 1}, {id: 2}]));
console.log(hasObject([{id: 1}, {id:2}, 'a', 'b']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count the objects and use it for one of the three types to return.

```js
function getType(array) {
    var count = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + (typeof a === 'object');
    }, 0);
    
    return count === array.length
        ? 'array of objects'
        : count
            ? 'mix values'
            : 'normal';
}

console.log([
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
    [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, 'a', 'b']
].map(getType));
```

Answer (score 0):

With a type check on array

```
const hasObject = a => Array.isArray(a) && a.some(val => typeof val === 'object')
```