# Array of mixed types, but having minimum count of a certain type in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Let's say that I want to enforce strict typing on a given array, such that:

- It may contain any number (a.k.a. zero or more) of `number`
- It must contain one number or more of `string`

...and the order of `number` and `string` in the array does not matter, so that the following arrays are valid:

- `['foo', 1, 2, 3]`
- `[1, 2, 'foo', 3]`
- `['foo']`

But the following array is invalid:

- `[1, 2, 3]` (because it needs at least one `string` in the array)

The closest solution that *almost* worked for me is to define the type as:

```
/**
 * Array must contain:
 * - One or more string
 * - Zero or more numbers
 * @type
 */
type CustomArray = [string] & Array<number | string>

const a: CustomArray = ['foo', 1, 2, 3]; // Should pass (works as expected)
const b: CustomArray = [1, 2, 'foo', 3]; // Should pass (but doesn't with my code)
const c: CustomArray = ['string'];       // Should pass (works as expected)
const d: CustomArray = [1, 2, 3];        // Should fail (works as expected)
```

But this means that the *first* element of the array must be a string, instead of enforcing a minimum count of 1 throughout the array. [You can test it out on TypeScript Playround here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PQKhCgAIUhBAneBDAnpAtgVwM4BdIDGA9gHa5ICWJAXFDALSQDyJAppEfBp+3vFQHM6kRgC1W8Ihy7oekEpnQAjCdmEABXCgAOrOsHBbdkAMI5cRdAmRoAvJADafQQF1IAMjiJUAHgXKJSAAfSGcSAQA+cHBiEjxIJGpTc0trVEh7BwByADMiIiyAGkgARmKAJmKAZhcAbkhgYEgAZQALIkwAGwATSG0kbGxIAAoAd04AayGByFYAD10CXFZugEoY0nilJLM8VO87RzLISshc-KLIGvrGlvau3v7BkaVMfG6iVmwSLPxRilwrQwaGI3VY61i8QIOxSVgOGUcWTCAiydUg6IxDSabQ6PT6AyGY0m0yG80WyzWGzi7xhezhNgRDmOp2umMxtxxD0gOUonRG43gUwSpIWrCWK1WQA).

Comment: Is it feasible to rather use a custom type guard? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYEEBOmCGIoC8UWuIAPAHZyoBGEmUAPlEpgJYUDmAfANwBQ-AGZwKAY2BtkFKGwTwkaEngAUOTJwBcUHBRABKbes6yEsRCgzY8UAN78ojqJgjA4mGcpAA6OV7Ua+lAAZMFQASY4ZrogANoAuvreCGgQKgwE3FCgkMhC6UEERVAA5KwcnCX6AgC+gvxi0kg62gqWXoRQsSVCyMglADRQAIxDAExDAMzxAo0UzTStFkrW+ESxo1ATpb39UzMNTcBQYkuKVqSd3bslB4fzxwAmZ+2rV8N3bELhcm0rpGp9EF7E4Tk1kAAbCDeCHITgqEo4Uw6cznLxVWr8L4-eTLC6qR5AuwOJxzFJQmFwhGPZFIv74kAY-h1CAQhDQEGk8EU2Hwko0uRQAByAHkACoo+no6rMoA

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910889/typescript-array-with-minimum-length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to tell TypeScript that an array should contain *at least* one element of a specific type.

The best you can do is just create an number / string array:

```
type CustomArray = (number | string)[];
```

Or

```
type CustomArray = Array<number | string>;
```

And then add the [required checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663426/how-to-check-if-array-contains-at-least-one-object) where you're adding or reading data to / from the array.

Comment: How about adding a `& { _isCustomArray: true }`, then typecast with a check.

Comment: @JonasWilms: how would that validate the requirement of having at least one string entry?

Comment: `function asCustomArray(array: (string | number)[]): CustomArray | never { ... }`

Comment: .... or just using a custom type guard?....Though that won't do a strict type check before runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be an idea?

```js
/**
 * Array must contain:
 * - One or more string
 * - Zero or more numbers
 * @type
 */
console.clear();

const CustomArray = (arr: Array<string | number>) => {
  if (!arr.length) {
    return new TypeError("Invalid: array should contain at least one element");
  }

  const oneString = arr.filter(v => v.constructor === String).length;
  const wrongTypes = arr.filter(v => v.constructor !== Number && v.constructor !== String).length && true || false;
  
  if (wrongTypes) {
    return new TypeError(`Invalid: [${JSON.stringify(arr)}] contains invalid types`);
  }

  if (!oneString) {
    return new TypeError(`Invalid: [${JSON.stringify(arr)}] should contain at least one String value`);
  }
  
  return arr;
};

type MyArray = Array<string | number> | TypeError;

const a: MyArray = CustomArray(['foo', 1, 2, 3]); // Should pass (works as expected)
const b: MyArray = CustomArray([1, 2, 'foo', 3]); // Should pass (works as expected)
const c: MyArray = CustomArray(['string']);       // Should pass (works as expected)
const d: MyArray = CustomArray([1, 2, 3]);        // Should fail (works as expected)

const log = (v:any) => 
  console.log(v instanceof TypeError ? v.message : JSON.stringify(v));

log(a);
log(b);
log(c);
log(d);
```

Comment: Then why wouln't you just use `CustomArray` instead of `MyArray`?

Comment: `arr as MyArray` would make sense then. Also returning an error is really ugly

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I'm not looking for a function that does that check: just a type definition that fulfills the requirements. Looks like it's not possible right now.

Comment: @Terry, no problem. I must confess that I seldom feel the need to use typescript.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no way to have a compile-time check for an array having a minimum size of a specific type.

---

What follows is a runtime-check-based solution:

Instead of having an array of different types, I would introduce a tuple of strings and numbere.

```
type Custom = [number[], string[]];
```

You then can define a check function to see if it fulfills your requirement:

```
const isValid = (c: Custom): boolean => {
    const [_, strings] = c;

    return strings.length >= 1;
};
```

If you need your inputs as an array, you can transform them into tuples:

```
const toCustom = (a: (string | number)[]): Custom => {
    const numbers: number[] = [];
    const strings: string[] = [];

    a.forEach((element) => {
        if (typeof element === "string") {
            strings.push(element);
        } else if (typeof element === "number") {
            numbers.push(element);
        } else {
            throw new Error("Unexpected type given"); // for runtime errors
        }
    });

    return [
        numbers,
        strings
    ];
}
```

And then you can enforce runtime checks:

```
const a = isValid(toCustom([
    "foo",
    1,
    2,
    3
])); // Should pass
const b = isValid(toCustom([
    1,
    2,
    "foo",
    3
])); // Should pass

const c = isValid(toCustom(["string"]));       // Should pass 
const d = isValid(toCustom([
    1,
    2,
    3
])); // should fail

console.log(a, b, c, d); // prints: true true true false
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I'm not looking for a function that does that check: just a type definition that fulfills the requirements. Looks like it's not possible right now.

Comment: Re: "_There appears to be no way to have a compile-time check for an array having a minimum size of a specific type._"

Is this based on an open issue / ticket from TS? Or just your conclusion based on looking around?

Answer (score 0):

There might be one option to force a minimum size of an array, yet it only works well with a tupled approach:

```
type OneOrMore<T> = {
    0: T
} & T[]
type Custom = [number[], OneOrMore<string>];

const bar: Custom = [
    [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    ["bar"],
];

const foo: Custom = [
    [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    [], // missing zero property
];
```