# Type array with optional Ts, required Ks

Tags: typescript, types

I want to type an array as needing at least one or more strings at any index, with any extra elements being numbers,

```
type NumberArrayWithAtleastOneString = [...(number[] | string)[], string]

const a: NumberArrayWithAtleastOneString = [1,'hello',3] // should work
const b: NumberArrayWithAtleastOneString = ['hello', 3, 'world'] // should work
const d: NumberArrayWithAtleastOneString = ['hello'] // should work
const c: NumberArrayWithAtleastOneString = [1,2,3] // should fail
const e: NumberArrayWithAtleastOneString = [] // should fail
```

However, all of the variables raise an error, with `const a` alerting

```
Type '[number, string, number]' is not assignable to type 'NumberArrayWithAtleastOneString'.
  Type at positions 0 through 1 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | number[]'.ts(2322)
```

So what is the correct notation? Or is there not a way to do this in TypeScript?

Comment: Even with your example code, how would `['hello', 3, 'world']` be valid? I would expect that `type` construct (if it were valid) to check for exactly one string with any amount of numbers on either side. In typical OOP design, you'd really have an array with either the parent type between the two, or as a union type.

Comment: ①  Presumably you really mean `[...(number | string)[], string, ...(number | string)[]]`. Which still doesn't work but at least conveys "array of numbers and strings with at least one string". Could you edit to clarify? ② Once you do that: no, this is not possible in TS with a specific type.  The best you could do is write a generic type and a helper function to aid inference, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NDAZxm). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Edited my post. Yes, I'd appreciate and accept a write-up on that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array of mixed types, but having minimum count of a certain type in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249336/array-of-mixed-types-but-having-minimum-count-of-a-certain-type-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to write a specific `NumberArrayWithAtLeastOneString` type in TypeScript that meets your requirements.  [Tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) can either have a single [trailing rest element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) or a single [leading or middle rest element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types), but cannot currently have both.

The closest you can get is to write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `NumberArrayWithAtLeastOneString<T>` type instead that acts like a *constraint* on `T`, so that `T` is valid if and only if `T extends NumberArrayWithAtLeastOneString<T>`.

We could write that like this:

```
type NumberArrayWithAtLeastOneString<T extends (string | number)[]> =
    T extends (
        { [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends string ? unknown : never }[number]
    ) ? T : [...T, string]
```

Here we are checking `T` against a [mapped array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `{ [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends string ? unknown : never }` into which we [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `number`.  If any of the elements of `T` are assignable to `string`, that becomes `unknown`, and therefore `T extends unknown` is true, and the whole thing is `T`.  If none of the elements are assignable to `string`, that becomes `never`, and therefore `T extends never` is false, and the whole thing becomes `[...T, string]`.  So if there's a string in `T` somewhere, then `NumberArrayWithAtLeastOneString<T>` is `T`.  Otherwise, it's `T` with a `string` added to the end.

---

It's not fun to use `NumberArrayWithAtLeastOneString<T>` directly in a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables), like this:

```
const a: NumberArrayWithAtLeastOneString<[1, "hello", 3]> = [1, "hello", 3];
```

It forces you to write out your type argument explicitly which is redundant.  You'd like to just *infer* the type argument, but TS doesn't support that for generic types. Instead you can write a generic utility *function* that just returns its input.  And generic functions *do* infer type arguments when calling them. Like this:

```
const numberArrayWithAtLeastOneString = <T extends (string | number)[]>(
    ...t: NumberArrayWithAtLeastOneString<T>
) => t;
```

Now instead of writing

```
const v: NumberArrayWithAtLeastOneString<⋯> = [⋯];
```

you can write

```
const v = numberArrayWithAtLeastOneString(⋯);
```

which is a lot easier and quite similar to your originally intended

```
const v: NumberArrayWithAtLeastOneString = [⋯];
```

in terms of effort.

Let's try it:

```
const a = numberArrayWithAtLeastOneString(1, 'hello', 3); // okay
const b = numberArrayWithAtLeastOneString('hello', 3, 'world'); // okay
const d = numberArrayWithAtLeastOneString('hello'); // okay
const c = numberArrayWithAtLeastOneString(1, 2, 3); // error
const e = numberArrayWithAtLeastOneString(); // error
```

Looks good.  The last two examples fail with an error saying that you haven't provided enough arguments, because it's expecting a `string` you haven't yet provided.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4EFWoIYgOoCWwAFusADITYDOwA8gHYQDKwqBDA5gDwAqUEAB7AIDACbUoAClrsuUAD5QGiFKgCUAbQC6APigBeAFBRTUfkJHjJUk2fsBvKJoCSUDlADWEEAHsAZubaAFzmrtoCwqISULIcnFAA-FBwDJ4MvgDuDFChTABuaFAAvpoqyGjadqbqSea5zgB0zbwANLFs8VVGAMa+DLTKqmiYOPhEpBRUtIwsnfIGUHyRVjEy8wlK5Wpaerb2zY3AofAVGFi4hCRklDT0TKxyPLy6RrUG+sAA3Ea9-YMgOCeE7Dc5jK6TW4zB4bbiaACM7QARMQIAAbNG+JHtADMekMzkRUBR6Mx2KgeJ+fwGwCg2AJ2xGF3G1ymd1mj3iUiJAHJURjfDzceofn0aVAkAzQaNLhMbtN7nMnlI+aTBbj2jzMr5UGixDyRVAAPRG2LEXxwPVQbWoTzUwZiKVnGUsyEKjkbFX8zEGr7G03Uc2Wx02u1iwY9J1qF0Q+XsmHKokAJmFfpNZotVv82AIaPttOgi0ZYNlrKhis5XCkhvTgczjuzuaMQA)