# How do I change the value of an item in a Set?

Tags: javascript, set

I have a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) that I want to update in JavaScript, but I can't figure out anything that lets me update values within it.

```
const mySet = new Set([]);
mySet.add('hello');
mySet.add('hewwo');
mySet.add('henlo');
```

I've tried syntax like

`mySet['hello'] = 'hello world'`,

`mySet.hello = 'hello world'`, and

`mySet[0] = 'hello world'`.

I've also tried modifying the value like this:

```
mySet.forEach(item => {
  if (item === 'hello') {
    item = 'hello world';
  }
})
```

Nothing has worked for me so far though. I wanted to use a set over a normal array because it prevents duplicate items automatically, but should I just add the logic myself? Is there a good use case for sets in `JavaScript` if I can't modify the values in them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to "modify" a (primitive) item would be to remove it from the Set and then add the altered item.

```js
const mySet = new Set([]);
mySet.add('hello');
mySet.add('hewwo');
mySet.add('henlo');

if (mySet.has('hello')) {
  mySet.delete('hello');
  mySet.add('hello world');
}

console.log(...mySet);
```

If you want to change each item, either iterate over each item, deleting and adding again, or (as would probably be easier) transform it into an array and `.map` into a new Set.

While you *can* do this, it's still a *pretty weird* thing to want to do. It's useful to think of Sets as *unordered* collections, which can have values individually added or removed.

One big reason sets are useful is that looking up values in them is an `O(1)` operation, unlike with arrays (where lookup requires `O(n)` time).

Comment: `delete` returns whether the element was present, so `has` is unnecessary: `if (mySel.delete("hello")) mySet.add("hello world")`

Comment: Yep, that's possible, but it's a lot stranger to read IMO (many people seeing that would probably look up what `.delete` returns first)

Answer (score 2):

In `Set` you need to delete the previously available value and than add new one if you want to replace already existing value,

One alternative when you want to replace key's  value regularly you can use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const myMap = new Map([]);
myMap.set('hello', 'hello');
myMap.set('hewwo', 'hewwo');
myMap.set('hello', 'Hello world')

console.log([...myMap.values()].join('\n')); 

// join('\n') is just for formatting output
```

Answer (score 1):

The **`Set`** lets you store **unique values**

For specified **key and a value** pairs use **`Map`**

```js
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('hello', 'hello');
myMap.set('hewwo', 'hewwo');
myMap.set('henlo', 'henlo');

myMap.set('hello', 'hello world');

console.log(myMap.get('hello'))

console.log(...myMap.entries())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a set and I wanted to update values that may contains duplicate during update. This is what I did

```
let test = new Set([1,2,3]);
let tmpSet = new Set();
for (let num of test) {
    tmpSet.add(num+1);
    
}
test = tmpSet;
console.log(tmpSet); // [2,3,4]
```