# AWS Lambda: How to update item in a map in Dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to increment the values of items in a MAP attribute called *provinceDistribution* in my Dynamodb table during aggregation in a lambda function, based on the *province* field of a user record.

Table model:

```
type submissionsAggregate @model {
  id: String
  totalRecords: Int
  provinceDistribution: provinces
  status: employmentStatus
  females: Int
  males: Int
}
type provinces {
  Sichuan: Int
  Qinghai: Int
  Gansu: Int
  Heilongjiang: Int
  Yunnan: Int
  Hunan: Int
  Shaanxi: Int
  Hebei: Int
  ...
}
```

User record:

```
   {
     "Timestamp": {
        "S": "2016-11-18:12:09:36"
      },
      "province": {
        "S": "Sichuan"
      },
      "gender": {
        "S": "male"
      },
      "employmentStatus": {
        "S": "employed"
      }
   }
```

I extracted the *province* field value and stored it in the **ExpressionAttributeValues**, hoping to create a path to the targeted item in the MAP(*#province*) during update like so

```
const params = {
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#total": "totalRecords",
      // "#status": "status",
      "#males": "males",
      "#females": "females",
      "#select": "Sichuan",
      "#province": "provinceDistribution",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":inc": 1,
      // ":targetStatus": `#status.${employmentStatus}`,
      ":targetProvince": `#province.${province}`,
      ":maleIncrement": maleIncrement,
      ":femaleIncrement": femaleIncrement,
    },
    Key: {
      id: "statistics1",
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
    TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
    UpdateExpression:
      "set #province=:targetProvince + :inc, #total=#total+ :inc, #males =#males+:maleIncrement, #females=#females+ :femaleIncrement",
  };
```

Then I get this error:

> 'Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: +, operand type: S',

Kind of the main issue is knowing how to traverse the Map dynamically. Say provinceDistribution.Sichuan, where "Sichuan" is the province extracted from the user record in order to increment its value in the Map.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is `set #province=:targetProvince + :inc`. You are trying to concatenate a number with a string, which is not supported by UpdateExpressions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html

Comment: oh I see, so what would you suggest I do in this situation?

Comment: Depending what you are trying to do, but if province is a string it seems no sense to try to increment it

Comment: What I want to do is increment the target province in the provinceDistribution map whenever it gets targeted. Eg provinceDistribution:{Sichuan:1}

Comment: As I see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51920174/7409146, `set #province.#select=:targetProvince + :inc`

Comment: I did try that and ended up getting the same error.