# DynamoDB append a map to list in a map in a list in a map in a list

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have the follow attribute in a DynamoDB table (trust me, I know it's a mess):

```
"list1": [
  {
    "mapName": "map1",
    "list2": [
      {
        "mapName": "map2",
        "list3": [ #append map here
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to append a map to list3, and I am struggling with the syntax of how to make update_item do this. The position in list1 and list2 are stored in variables i and j respectively. I am trying something like this:

```
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'primary_key': item_name
    },
    UpdateExpression="SET list1[:i].list2[:j].list3 = list_append(list1[:i].list2[:j].list3, :x)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':x': map,
        ':i': i,
        ':j': j
    }
)
```

The error message I am getting with the code is at the update_item line:

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: \":i\", near: \"[:i]\"",
```

I'm guessing I will need some combination of ExpressionAttributeNames and ExpressionAttributeValues, but I am not very familiar with boto3 syntax. Any help on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the result of the code you've shown? Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911927/update-nested-map-dynamodb

Comment: Thanks for the response! The error message I am getting with the code is at the update_item line:

"errorMessage": "Unsupported type \"<class 'type'>\" for value \"<class 'map'>\"",
  "errorType": "TypeError",

And thanks for that link, I will see if it sheds any light.

Comment: Apologies, listed the wrong error, I have updated it again accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do what I wanted as follows:

```
string = f"SET list1[{i}].list2[{j}].list3 = list_append(list1[{i}].list2[{j}].list3, :x)"
            
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'primary_key': item_name
    },
    UpdateExpression=string,
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':x': [map]
    }
)
```

Not the most elegant solution, if anyone can show how to do this without the fstring, please post an additional answer.

Comment: There are 2 changes here: 1) using the f-string and 2) changing `':x': map` to `':x': [map]`). Were both required, or just the latter?

Comment: Hey jarmod, yes, both changes were required. The f-string got around the syntax issues with the UpdateExpression, and the [map] got around another issue with list_append; as I understand it, list_append takes two lists as arguments so :x does need to be a list object. Please let me know if I can expand any more.