# How to check if variable is an object or an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem that i didn't know how to solve it, i have test some information of how i should comparing or checking a variable if it was an `array` or an `object`

I have tried this

```
console.log({} == []); // return false
console.log({1:"haha"} == {}); // return false
console.log(["haha"] == {}); // retun false
```

The problem is, that i want to know if a variable is actualy an `object` cause `typeof` of both `[]` or `{}` return `object`.

```
console.log(isobject({1:"haha"})) // should return true;
console.log(isobject(["haha"])); // should return false;
```

Or

```
console.log(isobject({})) // should return true;
console.log(isobject([])); // should return false;
```

Is there any `function` to check `variable` like above?
Thanks for any correction.

Comment: array instanceof Array //Output true , can also check  is it array or not

Comment: @NinjaJami how to implement it? `array instanceof Array` ?

Comment: You can do like  var arr=[1]; if(arr instanceof Array){}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would help.

```js
var a = [], b = {};

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(a).indexOf("Array")>-1);
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(b).indexOf("Object")>-1);

console.log(a.constructor.name == "Array");
console.log(b.constructor.name == "Object");
```

There are many other ways, but the above is backward compatible in all browsers.

Related questions must be referred:

[Check if a value is array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-an-array)

[Check if a value is object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Why the `indexOf` check, and not just a plain comparison? You can also check the name of the constructor

Comment: how can i check the name of the constructor? @CertainPerformance

Comment: @IrvanHilmi Updated the answer.

Comment: @IrvanHilmi eg `[].constructor.name === 'Array'` (though `Array.isArray` is better for arrays) and `({}).constructor.name === 'Object'`

Answer (score 5):

`arr = [1,2,3]`

`Array.isArray(arr)` // should output true

for object I would do 
`obj = {a:1}`

`Object.keys(obj).length` // should output 1

so you could do

`Object.keys(obj).length >= 0` // should be true if obj is obj literal.

Comment: _`Object.keys(obj).length` // should output 1_

`arr = [5]` will also output 1 for `Object.keys(arr).length`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var jsonData = {
  Name:"Jonh Doe",
  Dept: {
    code: "cse",
    title: "Computer science & tech"
  },
  Courses: [
    {
      code: "cse123",
      name: "something"
    },{
      code: "cse123",
      name: "something"
    }
  ]
}

for(var item in jsonData){
  if(typeof jsonData[item] === "object"){
    var x = "";
    if(Array.isArray(jsonData[item])) x = "Array";
    else x = "object";
    console.log(item + " is " + x);
  }else{
    console.log(item + " is " + typeof jsonData[item]);
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.stringify(variable).startsWith("[")
```

This will return true when variable is an array.

```
JSON.stringify(variable).startsWith("{")
```

This will return true when variable is an object.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient. The fact that this is even suggested is outrageous.