# How to check if object is empty in javascript for all levels in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, is-empty

I wanted to find out if my object is empty or not for all its nested objects and key-value pairs.

for e.g.,

```
const x = {
  a:"",
  b:[],
  c:{
    x:[]
  },
  d:{
    x:{
      y:{
        z:""
      }
    }
  }
};
```

this should be an empty object and if any of this contains single value then it should be non empty.

Comment: Would you be able to show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the way to do what using **recursion**

```js
const x = {
  a:"",
  b:[],
  c:{
    x:[]
  },
  d:{
    x:{
      y:{
        z:''
      }
    }
  }
};
function checkEmpty(obj){
  
  for(let key in obj){
    //if the value is 'object'
    if(obj[key] instanceof Object === true){
      if(checkEmpty(obj[key]) === false) return false;
    }
    //if value is string/number
    else{
      //if array or string have length is not 0.
      if(obj[key].length !== 0) return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(checkEmpty(x))
x.d.x.y.z = 0;
console.log(checkEmpty(x));
```

Comment: its perfectly working on all conditions, thanks man! you got it right 0 is not null anywhere here for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a recursive function like following. Function creates a set with 2 possible values true and false. If the size of set is 1 and the value being false, which mean that the object is empty.

```js
const x = {a:"",b:[],c:{x:[]},d:{x:{y:{z:""}}}};

function isEmpty(o, r = new Set()) {
  for (let k in o) {
    if(typeof o[k] === "object") {
      if(Array.isArray(o[k])) r.add(!!o[k].length);
      else isEmpty(o[k],r);
    } else r.add(!(o[k] === "" || o[k] === undefined || o[k] === null));
  }
  return r;
}
let result = isEmpty(x);

console.log(result.has(false) && result.size == 1);
```

Comment: It `return true` for `0` inside object

Answer (score 1):

I will use a recursive approach for this one, we iterate over the `object.keys()` and check is every value related to the key is empty, in the case the value is an object, we go one level deeper to check it.

```js
const x = {
  a:"",
  b:[],
  c:{x:[]},
  d:{x:{y:{z:""}}}
};

const x1 = [0,0,0];
const x2 = {0:0,1:0,2:0};

const isEmpty = (obj, empty=true) =>
{
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) =>
    {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object")
            empty = isEmpty(obj[key], empty);
        else
            empty = empty && (obj[key].length === 0);
            
        // Return early if we detect empty here.
        
        if (!empty) return empty;
    });
    
    return empty;
}

console.log("original x: ", isEmpty(x));

x.a = "I'm not empty";

console.log("x after edit: ", isEmpty(x));
console.log("x1: ", isEmpty(x1));
console.log("x2: ", isEmpty(x2));
```

Comment: You code will return `true` even if there will a value `0`

Comment: @MaheerAli I really don't understand well what he consider empty, in his example this `{z:""}` is considered empty. For me that is not empty. If he clarify with other cases I will update the answer, however the approach will be similar. Could you give me an example where my code fails, so I can analize it...

Comment: use `x.a = 0;` and then check it will return `true`

Comment: For example, will this be an empty object `[0,0,0]` or not? If no, then `{0:0, 1:0, 2:0}` should not be considered empty also.

Comment: neither `[0,0,0]` should be considered empty not `{0:0, 1:0, 2:0}`. In his question he showed only `[]` and `''`

Answer (score 1):

try (we use here [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), [fat arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [obj. keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and [object checking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458052/860099))

```
let isEmpty = o => o.constructor.name === "Object" ? 
  Object.keys(o).reduce((y,z)=> y&&isEmpty(o[z]) ,true) : o.length == 0;
```

```js
const x = {
  a:"",
  b:[],
  c:{
    x:[]
  },
  d:{
    x:{
      y:{
        z:""
      }
    }
  }
};


let isEmpty = o => o.constructor.name === "Object" ? 
    Object.keys(o).reduce((y,z)=> y&&isEmpty(o[z]) ,true) : o.length == 0;
  


// Test
console.log(isEmpty(x));
x.d.x.y.z="Smile to life and life will smile to you";
console.log(isEmpty(x));
```