# How to check the key in the object is an object

Tags: javascript

My exercises are use for...in to print out all the keys in the object, print out the keys of the nested objects. But i don't check if the value of nameValue is object

I tried to using for...in but but the result of the value check is undefined

```js
// My Exercises 
var apartment = {
  bedroom: {
    area: 20,
    bed: {
      type: 'twin-bed',
      price: 100
    }
  }
};

// Tried
function checkObj(objs) {
  for (var obj in objs) {
    console.log(obj);
    var check = objs['obj'];
    console.log(check);
  }
}
checkObj(apartment);
```

Comment: I believe there is an isObject function in javascript

Comment: You may want to use `objs[obj]` instead of `objs['obj']`

Comment: How to know if that value is an object

Comment: Do you want to check if the value is object `{}` and return `false` if it is an array `[]` or `null` ? because all 3 are `objects` in JavaScript

Comment: Don't forget functions are also objects.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript `typeof null`, `typeof []`, and `typeof {}` will return `'object'`.

You can check if the `constructor.name` of the `object` is equal to `'Object'`

```
function checkObj(objs) {
    for (var obj in objs) {
        var isObj = objs[obj] && objs[obj].constructor.name === 'Object';
        console.log('is Object:', isObj);
    }
}

checkObj(apartment);
```

As @ZivBen-Or suggested in the comments, you can also check it like this

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === "[object Object]"
```

Comment: Your idea is very good. I just learned Javascript so I don't know

Comment: @AgnesK.Rivers I think that now that you know all of them are `objects`, you should edit the question and include if you want to check for arrays `[]` or `null`s or just an object as `{}`

Comment: Another way is: `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === "[object Object]"`

Comment: @ZivBen-Or Thanks for sharing, I will include it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to determine if the value is object or not?

```
function isObject (item) {
  return (typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item) && item !== null);
}
```

as `typeof []` is also an `object`

```js
var apartment = {
    bedroom: {
        area: 20,
        bed: {
        type: 'twin-bed',
        price: 100
        },
        test:[1,2,3]
    }
};

function isObject (item) {
  return (typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item) && item !== null);
}

function checkObj(objs) {
    for (var obj in objs) {
        console.log(obj);
        var check = isObject(objs[obj]);
        console.log(check);
    }
}
checkObj(apartment);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8511281/2845389)

Comment: What about function value?

Answer (score 0):

Print all keys and values by checking if the dipper level is object or not.

> ```
> objs[obj] !== null && typeof objs[obj] === 'object' && objs[obj].constructor !== Array
> ```
>
> This is the way you can identify if object.

Updated to validate `null` and `array`.

```js
// My Exercises 
var apartment = {
    bedroom: {
        area: 20,
        bed: {
        type: 'twin-bed',
        price: 100
        }
    },
    bedroom1: null,
    bedroom2: [],
    bedroom3: {}
};

// Tried
function checkObj(objs) {
    for (var obj in objs) {
     if (objs[obj] !== null && typeof objs[obj] === 'object' && objs[obj].constructor !== Array) {
      checkObj(objs[obj]);
     } else {
      console.log(obj, ':', objs[obj]);
     }
    }
}
checkObj(apartment);
```

Comment: it wouldn't work correct if the value of the property is an `Array` or `function` `Object`

Comment: @ZivBen-Or, OP has already shared sample JSON and OP already said that him exercise is completed. According to OP sample JSON, this is the enough and minimal condition to identify an object.

Comment: How to check value is array or object or fucntion object and null

Comment: @AgnesK.Rivers, then you should include your requirement in question. Please update the question. I will try to update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, basically everything is an object.Try this method to distinguish the broader `Object prototype` from an object `of key/value
pairs ({}).`I have given you an example you can try this in your code to see it better.I have appended your code too.

```js
var apartment = {
    bedroom: {
        area: 20,
        bed: {
        type: 'twin-bed',
        price: 100
        }
    }
};

var isPlainObject = function (obj) {
 return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]';
};

console.log(isPlainObject(apartment));

console.log(isPlainObject(apartment.bedroom));
console.log(isPlainObject(apartment.bedroom.bed));


// Returns false
console.log(isPlainObject(['wolverine', 'magneto', 'cyclops']))
// returns false
console.log(isPlainObject(null))


// Your code

function checkObj(objs) {
    for (var obj in objs) {
      
        var check = isPlainObject(objs[obj]);
        console.log("your code",check); // this returns true
    }
}
checkObj(apartment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive function that runs on the object keys and if the value of the proprty is an `object` it calls the function again.
I used `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === "[object Object]"` and not `typeof obj[key] === 'object'` to check is the property is an object on an object and not and object of `Array` or a `function`

```js
var apartment = {
    bedroom: {
        area: 20,
        bed: {
            type: "twin-bed",
            price: 100,
            array: [1,2,3],
            method: function(){}
        }
    }
}

function printObjectKeys(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        console.log(key);
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === "[object Object]") {
            printObjectKeys(obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(printObjectKeys(apartment));
```

Comment: I didn't copy paste your answer 