# How to check if a value in object is a primitive?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, primitive

So basically i want to check if my data (which is in JSON Format) has a value which is a primitive. So let's take an Example: I get data that looks like this: {name: Artikel, value: {"ArtNr": 1234}} and i want to check if 1234 is primitive or not. I also want to differentiate if the result is an Array with Primitives in it or an Object. Is that possible?

```
function isObjectContainingPrimitiveValues(test) {
        let values = Object.values(test);
        for (let i of values) {
            console.log(i);
            return (typeof i === 'string' || typeof i === 'number' || typeof i === 'boolean' || typeof i === null || typeof i === undefined);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

So with the awesome help of MaxK i have built a `isResultContainingPrimitiveValues()` Function which checks my data for Primitive/ Primitive Arrays and or Objects. The following part is the trickiest at least with my understanding. The following Example will hopefully help you understand my problems better.

So my `let namesSplit = treeNode.name.split('.');` variable splits the data it gets and has as a result of `nameSplit : Artikel,Artnr`. Next i defined a key variable `let key = namesSplit[0];` which has `key : Artikel` as a result. Than i define a contextEntry variable `let contextEntry = exprData.contextEntry.find(_x => _x.name === key);` and has `contextEntry : {"name":"Artikel","value":{"ArtNr":123}}` as a result. Now i want to check: if there's another split `namesSplit.length > 1` check `isResultContainingPrimitiveValues()`. If it is primitive, throw an error, if it is an object -> get values from it and if it is an array -> get values form there. I know it's a lot but from all the confusing stuff i can't seem to think clear, so i appreciate every help i can get.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question is. But Object accepts a parameter and returns an Object so if  Object(test) !==test then test is primitive

Comment: So i get back an Object which has a key and a value in it (example: 'ArtNr':  1423). And i want to check the value against my isPrimitive funciton

Comment: `typeof i === null || typeof i === undefined` won't happen (the `typeof` operator **always** returns a string). I think you want `typeof i === 'undefined' || i === null`.

Comment: Your function is named `isPrimitive` but it accepts an `object` argument - you should rename the function to `isObjectContainingOnlyPrimitiveValues` or something more specific, because an `object` value (besides `null`) is not a primitive value.

Comment: Thanks and i'll try that. (I also have updated my question, i hope it's more clear now)

Comment: You are right i just did that, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a value is an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: I've seen that post (before i created mine) but apparently it does not help me...

Answer (score 2):

You are returning from your function on the first iteration. You should only return false if you found an non-primitive and if you were able to loop over all values you can return true because all values are primitives:

```
function isObjectContainingPrimitiveValues(testObj) {
  let values = Object.values(testObj);
  for(let i of values){
     if (typeof i === 'object') {
       return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
};
```

### Update:

After reading your comment i changed the code to check for arrays with primitives as well. The idea is, to create a new function which only checks if a single value is a primitive.Now if we find an array, we can simply check - with the help 
 of the arrays some function - if some element, inside the array is not primitive. If so return false,otherwise we do the same checks as before:

```
function isObjectContainingPrimitiveValues(testObj) {
  let values = Object.values(testObj);
  for (let i of values) {
    if (Array.isArray(i)) {
      if (i.some(val => !isPrimitive(val)))
        return false;
    } else {
      if (!isPrimitive(i))
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

function isPrimitive(test) {
  return typeof test !== 'object'
}
```

Comment: Ok i'll try your solution, but i also need to differentiate if my Data object is an array with primitives in it , how would i go about this?

Comment: So you want isObjectContainingPrimitiveValues to also return true if some values are arrays with only primitives?

Comment: Yes exactly but i don't have any idea

Comment: Thank you very much i also have one last question if you got the time (sorry for always updating my question)

Comment: Sorry, i don't get it. So you checked contextEntry with the isObjectContainingPrimitiveValues and now you want to do the same procedure for every element in namesSplit ?

Comment: I know it‘s a little bit complex and probably didn’t explain it well too but we build an expression language and we get back the data in a tree structure which we recursive check. The Tree Structure is the namesSplit and the data is the contextEntry

Answer (score 0):

Array and object types all return a 'typeof' 'object'. so you can check against an object instead of checking against multiple conditions.
So the return statement will be:
`return (typeof i === 'object')`.
Number, string, undefined, null will all return false on the statement above.

Comment: Why? I don't get it 100%, would you mind explaining it a little more detailed? Why would Number, String, etc return false?

Comment: The value that get's back could also have an result which looks like this:          
{ name: "Artikel", value: {[Artnr: 1234]}}

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it's incorrect. Run this in your console: `var x = null; console.log( typeof x );` will output `'object'`. See here: https://2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html