# Angualar firestore _methodName FieldValuea.serverTimestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I need to store a server timestamp to my firestore document 

from the internet I got this code `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` but after I using this code in firestore it stored as like this `_methodName FieldValuea.serverTimestamp`

What is the issue and how to fix this?
my ts code  `

```
 let m1 = new Message();
    m1.doctor = this.uid;
    m1.patient = this.messageList[this.messageList.length - 1].patient;
    m1.isPatient = false;
    m1.message = event.message;


    m1.date = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      m1.reply = true,
      // type: files.length ? 'file' : 'text',
      //files: files,
      m1.user = {
        name: 'Jonh Doe',
        avatar: 'https://i.gifer.com/no.gif',
      },

      this.firestore.collection(Config.chatCollection).add(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(m1)));
`
```

```
class Message {
  user = {
    name: 'Jonh Doe',
    avatar: 'https://i.gifer.com/no.gif',
  }
  reply;
  doctor = "";
  text;
  date;
  cdate;
  isPatient = true;
  message = "";
  patient = "";
  time = "";
  documentID = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because you are doing

```
this.firestore.collection(Config.chatCollection).add(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(m1)));
```

By doing

```
this.firestore.collection(Config.chatCollection).add(m1);
```

it should be fine, since it seems that `m1` is a JavaScript Object.

The doc for the `add()` method is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add), you will see that its parameter shall be an "Object containing the data for the new document". If `m1` is a valid Object, you do not need to do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(m1))`, which corresponds to:

1. Transforming the `m1` JavaScript object into a JSON string, and
   then;
2. Taking the resulting JSON string and transforming it back into a
       JavaScript object.

Comment: ERROR FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.add() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: an object

Comment: Updated in question

Comment: Can you check if `m1` is an Object. E.g. by using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: PS: are you sure that your code does not contain the typo we can see in your question: `_methodName FieldValuea.serverTimestamp`. `FieldValuea` with an extra `a` instead of `FieldValue`