# Check if an object consists of nothing but empty objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a method to deeply determine whether or not an object consists of nothing but empty objects.

For example, that method should return true for each one of the following objects:

```
const obj1 = {};

const obj2 = {
    a: {}
    b: {}
    c: {}
};

const obj3 = {
    a: {
        a1: {}
    },
    b: {
        b1: {},
        b2: {}
    },
    c: {
        c1: {},
        c2: {},
        c3: {}
    }
};
```

And it should return false for the following object:

```
const obj4 = {
    a: {
        a1: {}
    },
    b: {
        b1: {},
        b2: {}
    },
    c: {
        c1: {},
        c2: {},
        c3: {
            x: 5
        }
    }
};
```

The simplest method I came up with is:

```
function isEmpty(object) {
    return typeof object === 'object' &&
           Object.keys(object).every(key => isEmpty(object[key]));
}
```

I couldn't find any counterexamples, so I'd like to ask if there are any flaws in this method.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that technically only the `obj1` is truly empty. The rest of the examples do not contain **only** empty objects. For example, the `obj3` object contains three properties that are *not* empty objects. They do have properties inside them. Nonetheless, I know what you mean. Just wanted to point out possible ambiguities ;)

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek: That's why I explicitly wrote `whether or not an object consists of nothing but empty objects` (both in the title of the question and in the opening statement).

Comment: Would this be a good candidate for  one of the SE code review sites?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can use a recursive function. Here are a few changes you could consider:

- Make sure to address `null` correctly (its `typeof` is "object"!)
- Use `Object.values` instead of `Object.keys`, so that...
- You can pass the function reference as-is to the `every` callback.
- You can make it an arrow function, using the expression syntax

```
const isDeepEmpty = obj => Object(obj) === obj &&  
                           Object.values(obj).every(isDeepEmpty);
```

Comment: `Object(obj) === obj` is equivalent to `typeof object === 'object'` with the exception of `null`?

Comment: Indeed, it is like you say.

Comment: Switching from `keys()` to `values()` is a neat idea!

Comment: Same goes for "pass the function reference as-is" (which I guess can be applied only after switching from `keys()` to `values()`.

Comment: Ah, I see you just added that point in a bullet.

Comment: How bad a performance impact is `Object(obj) === obj`?

Comment: I'm looking into [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript), and I don't even see that as a suggested method.

Comment: Why not measure the performance? If your object is such that you would have hundreds of thousands of calls, then it might matter, and you might be better of with a separate check for `null` (with `typeof obj === "object" && obj`). But for regular use, there should not be a noticeable difference. I always go for that in my code.

Comment: So how come it is not suggested in any of the answers to the question that I linked above?

Comment: Because it is locked and does not accept answers? But also because it asks a different question... The question is really ["how to check if a value is an object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript). It is suggested in the answer that got the bounty awarded.

Comment: I have searched for `Object(` conclusively in that post and couldn't find any. Also, that question says "What is the best way to compare objects in JavaScript?". Thank you very much, BTW.

Comment: You didn't follow my link then :) Here is a direct link to the answer in [Check if a value is an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706877/5459839)

Comment: Oh, you meant, that's the question that **I should have** been looking at. Got it! Thank you very much again :)

Comment: If we're listing flaws, and using things are aren't in the example (like null), then we should also point out that _circular references_ break it.  A JavaScript object can contain a property that refers to itself. E.g.: `ob1j.self = obj1` would be quicksand for your recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that's `null` will cause a TypeError, because `null` is type 'object', but it has no `keys()` method.

```js
const obj2 = {
  a: {},
  b: {},
  c: {
    d: null
  }
};

function isEmpty(object) {
  return typeof object === 'object' &&
    Object.keys(object).every(key => isEmpty(object[key]));
}

console.log(isEmpty(obj2));
// TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(object)')
```