# How to find object by key in a object?

Tags: javascript

`const obj={a:{b:{n:{d:1},m:{f:1}}}}`

How to find and return `{a:{b:{n:{d:1}}}}}` by key 'n'.

JSON parse stringify

Comment: That is a pretty specific operation, I doubt there is a native javascript function that does this. You'll need to traverse the object tree yourself, a recursive approach would probably the easiest.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly concise recursive solution. It avoids recursing on properties whose values aren't objects (Arrays are objects, thus the additional `.isArray()` check, and `null` is a special case)* and terminates when it finds an object whose `Object.keys()` include the passed key, otherwise it returns an empty object.

```js
const getNestedKeyPath = (obj, key) => {

  if (Object.keys(obj).includes(key)) {
    return { [key]: obj[key] };
  }

  for (const _key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (obj[_key] !== null && typeof obj[_key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[_key])) {
      const nextChild = getNestedKeyPath(obj[_key], key);
      if (Object.keys(nextChild).length !== 0) {
        return { [_key]: nextChild };
      }
    }
  };

  return {};
}

console.log(getNestedKeyPath(obj, 'n'))
```

```html
<script>
const obj = {
  c: {
    x: new Date(),
    y: undefined,
    d: {
      l: { w: [2, 3] },
      k: { l: null }
    }
  },
  a: {
    b: {
      n: { d: 1 },
      m: { f: 1 }
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

*This is not a definitive check but meets our needs. see: [JavaScript data types and data structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#data_and_structure_types) and [Check if a value is an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript/8511350#8511350)