# checking if an element is an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to check if an element is an object in javascript: 
`element.constructor == Object` Is this a correct way or there are more appropriate ways 
to check that? An alternate would be to use this - `typeof element === 'object'` 
There seem to be multiple ways to do that not sure which one is more appropriate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a value is an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, I will check that. Separately I found that most javascript documentation is available on https://developer.mozilla.org/ Is there any documentation for chrome too?

Answer (score 0):

It would be the easiest if you use the `lodash` package. Lodash is quite common in the js community and I really can recommend this in most cases.

> A modern JavaScript utility library delivering modularity, performance & extras.

Lodash docs of `isObject` function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isObject

> Checks if value is the language type of Object. (e.g. arrays, functions, objects, regexes, new Number(0), and new String(''))

**Example**

```
_.isObject({});
// => true
 
_.isObject([1, 2, 3]);
// => true
 
_.isObject(_.noop);
// => true
 
_.isObject(null);
// => false
```