# How to know if something is an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have a defined object in javascript like this:

```
jsObject = {
    objectName : 'some name',
    objectDescription: 'some description',
    objectDate: {
            day: '19',
            month: 'april',
            year: '2022'
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to determine what is an object (in terms of the structure, not in terms of 'everything in javascript is an object') and what isn't in order to do some later processing with the stored data. For example, objectDate is an object but objectName isn't, that is the kind of discrimination I want to do. Thank you all for the information.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: That won't work @AndyRay. `console.log(typeof []);`?

Comment: Also `console.log(typeof null)` will print "object" so `typeof` alone will not give you accurate results.

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf({}) == Object.prototype` is true

Comment: thans your help andy ray, that already solve my question

Comment: Also a duplicate for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @Andy Still works, it is easy enough to weed out the unwanted ones. `const isObject = item => item != null && typeof(item) == "object" && !Array.isArray(item)`