# How to check if data is key-value format in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'd like to know the solution to check the data format is key-value or not in react native. If someone knows it, let me know please. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a value is an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know a variable is instance of *Object* or not, you are be able to easily do this:

```js
if (typeof myVariable === 'object') {
  //do something
} else {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a = {'a':1,'b':2}
result = a instanceof Object && !(a instanceof Array)

result will be true if variable a contains key-value pairs.

- 'a instanceof Object' returns true when a is an array also. That is why the second condition is there.