# Update nested array immutably

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update a nested array immutably, but I get referential equality between the two results.

I'm expecting `updated.a !== obj.a` but I'm seeing in the console that they are equal.

```js
function update(dest, source) {
  return Object.entries(source).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      acc[key] = [...val];
    } else if (isPlainObject(val)) {
      acc[key] = { ...update(dest[key], source[key])
      };
    } else {
      acc[key] = val;
    }

    return acc;
  }, dest);
}

function isPlainObject(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]';
}

const obj = {
  a: [1, 2],
};

const updated = update(obj, {
  a: [1, 2]
});

console.log(updated.a === obj.a);
```

Comment: You need to deep copy `dest` when passing it to `reduce`. Immutable operations always require some sort of copying.

Comment: The problem is that you're updating `dest` in place, so `updated == obj`.

Comment: also `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)` isn't a very robust type check, see: [Check if a value is an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new copy of `dest` object using `Object.create`

```js
function update(dest, source) {
  return Object.entries(source).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      acc[key] = [...val];
    } else if (isPlainObject(val)) {
      acc[key] = { ...update(dest[key], source[key]) };
    } else {
      acc[key] = val;
    }

    return acc;
  }, Object.create(dest));
}

function isPlainObject(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]';
}

const obj = {
  a: [1, 2],
};

const updated = update(obj, { a: [1, 2] });

console.log(updated.a === obj.a);
```