# js object spreading (not sure what to call it )

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

is there any native way in js to transform an object from

```
{
    sample:{
        name:"joe",
        age:69
    }
}
```

to

```
{ 'sample.name': 'joe', 'sample.age': 69 }
```

i tried the following and it works for now but i'm not sure if this is the optimal way to do it

```js
let test = {
  sample: {
    name: 'joe',
    age: 69,
  },
}

for (let [pKey, pValue] of Object.entries(test)) {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(pValue)) {
    delete Object.assign(test, {
      [pKey + '.' + key]: value,
    })
    delete test[pKey]
  }
}

console.log(test);
```

Comment: No, there's nothing built-in that will do this.

Comment: you're changing a key so it's not the same thing.

Comment: Why do you need `delete` and `Object.assign`? Just do `test[pKey + '.' + key] = value;`

Comment: Of course one wonders why you need this at all? Possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

As I asked above in the comments; why do you think you want to do this?

If it is because you actually want to access the object using a dot delimited string

```
const name = { sample: { name: "joe", age: 69 } }['sample.name'];
```

then see: [Convert a JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-a-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference).

Be warned that the accepted answer offers a long explanation as to why that is bad practice (and if the accessing is, then the remapping as you've illustrated certainly is worse).

---

If having read that answer you still feel that you *need* to remap and flatten the object then you may as well make it work for arbitrarily deep objects.

```js
const input = {
  sample: {
    name: 'joe',
    age: 69,
    favorite: {
      food: 'pie',
      colors: ['pink', 'yellow']
    },
    birthday: (new Date(1980, 2, 18)) // excluded from result because Object.entries(Date).length === 0
  }
};

function recursivelyCombineKeys(obj) {
  const res = {};

  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (typeof v === 'object') {
      for (const [_k, _v] of Object.entries(recursivelyCombineKeys(v))) {
        res[`${k}.${_k}`] = _v
      }
    } else {
      res[k] = v
    }
  }

  return res
}

console.log(recursivelyCombineKeys(input));
```

***Note:*** The generic `typeof v === 'object'` check will match a number of built-in objects such as `Date` and `null`, and will also match arrays, so you may need to narrow it. see: [Check if a value is an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript)