# Hashtable vs objects In javascript

Tags: javascript, object, hashtable, javascript-objects

I’m new to data structure and I’m learning it in Javascript.

My Question is:
Why do we need hash tables when we 've objects in javascript?
Can anybody give me a situation where hash tables will be more useful than objects?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143522/4051471

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Hashtable" is called different things in different languages. Java has `Hashtable` and `HashMap`, Ruby has `Hash`, Python has `dict`... in JavaScript, it's called `Map`.

Objects' keys are limited to strings; `Map` keys can be anything.

Objects support inheritance; a `Map` only contains what is specifically put into it.

Answer (score 4):

Think you means Map instead of HashTable. IMHO Map may be more useful and perform better if you need one of that:

- keep order of insertions of key/value pairs;
- frequent additional and removal;
- key which not String/Symbol.

I think you can obtain more information at  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 0):

The MDN docs on this are quite helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared

Most notably, using a map gives you the advantage of using anything as a key, maps retain order, and may perform better when constantly adding and removing values.