# Can I use an object as hash table?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, hashtable, javascript-objects

let us suppose we create an object and use it to store some data 
`let x = {"john":true,"jack":true,"jim":false}` , what is the time complexity when I try to do `console.log(x["john"])`.
I have few doubts like, do objects perform similar to hash tables, can they be called hash tables, if not what is a very optimized way to implement a hash table in JavaScript

Comment: And by JSON you mean an object. [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: JSON is *only* text. Same as XML - it's just a serialisation format. What you have is a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: I've been assuming they're implemented as hashtables, because anything else would be crazy. But I haven't written a big enough application to notice the difference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143498/difference-between-an-object-and-a-hash